# graph.facebook not working as expected

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Why does this http://graph.facebook.com/mytrimet return this...

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

instead of the usual information about the page.  What simple thing have I overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like "mytrimet" is not a valid a valid object in Facebook. If this is an object created by you check if it is public. Check out http://graph.facebook.com/platform. It is the platform.

Comment: +1, this error almost certainly means the object can't be seen by the current viewer (or doesn't exist). For for pages usually this means there's demographic restrictions, for apps it's usually because it's in sandbox mode (or restricted), for users it usually means they've disabled platform apps entirely or have blocked the person whose access token you're using

Comment: Turned out to be the 'Country Restrictions' setting.  It was set to be visible in the US only.  However, once I removed all restrictions, it worked.  BTW, I'm in the US so I'm thinking this is a bug.  Thank you!

Comment: No, you probably weren't using a User access token for a user in the US